# Angular does not update inside a GMap object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am just starting to work with Angular and I am absolutely loving it, I am doing a Google Maps App running on Angular and have a problem updating my template inside a Google Map object, here is the code:

```
 Map.addMarker = function(objMarker){
        var overviewBox = 'some random text here';
        var GmapLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(objMarker.lat, objMarker.lng);
        var GmapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: overviewBox,
            maxWidth: 400
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position    : GmapLatLng,
            map         : MapApp.Gmap,
            icon        : '/images/nice-custom-marker.png',
            title       : objMarker.title,
            cleanTitle  : objMarker.cleanTitle
        });

        $scope.marker.title = "Hello from the add marker";
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            GmapInfoWindow.open(MapApp.Gmap, marker);
            Map.getMarker(marker.cleanTitle);
            $scope.marker.title = "Hello from the add marker listener";
        });
    }
```

I can replace my {{title}} on the template with "Hello from the add marker" but I cannot do the same inside of the click listener "Hello from the add marker listener" when I console.log($scope) I do have access to the $scope object though, I am very confused here, anybody knows about what might go wrong and how I can work around it?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Just tried with Jquery

```
$('#contentView>h1').text("Hello from the add listener");
$scope.marker.title = "Hello from the add listener";
```

and obviously it works but I really would like to use Angular instead :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to use `$scope.$apply();` after setting my variable, for a more in depth explanation you can read this [Angular .$apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)